# how to include external class css in html2pdf?

Tags: css, html2pdf

How do I add a class in html2pdf?
I have tested

```
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('../printpdf.css');
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Fixed general language.

Comment: hello language php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try with add css with `type="text/css"` to your html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```